# stop the progress bar in Activity A when i come from Activity B by using OnBackPressed()

Tags: android, android-intent, onbackpressed

I am moving from Activity A to Activity B. In Activity A when button is clicked progress bar becomes visible and it moves to Activity B. Now, In Activity B i have a back button and in click listener i added OnBackPressed(); method. Which is working fine but problem is the progress bar is still visible.

How can i stop the progress bar in Activity A when i come from Activity B.

Activity A:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    animateView(progressOverlay, View.VISIBLE, 0.4f, 200);
    Intent x = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
    startActivity(x);
}
```

Activity B:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_down, R.anim.slide_out_down);
}
```

Comment: can you please post you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In activity A add:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
animateView(progressOverlay, View.INVISIBLE, 0.4f, 200);
}
```

Basically add code to invisible your progress bar in this state of activity

Comment: Bro if it works dont forget to mark it as answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: It works but this code will work on each call of the onResume() method, not only if the app is passing between Activity A and Activity B

Comment: Yup it will do that you want only to do that when its switching between A and B only ?

Comment: for that create a boolean variable in class A and set it false, when you come back from B by passing value in intent update that boolean to true.After that in onResume apply check if that variable is true then hide it and set that variable false again otherwise dont make it invisibe. If you want it in that way let me know I will update my answer with this logic :)

Answer (score 1):

Activity A:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    animateView(progressOverlay, View.VISIBLE, 0.4f, 200);
    Intent x = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
    startActivityForResult(x,220);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK&&
                requestCode==220){
            animateView(progressOverlay, View.INVISIBLE, 0.4f, 200);
        }
    }
```

Activity B:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_down, R.anim.slide_out_down);
}
```